# how to use flatlist in react native with fetch api

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native with `laravel` back end so i just want to load list from `laravel` so for that i code like that

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data:[
        {
          student_name: '',
          class:'',
          section:'',
        }, 
      ],
    }
//id is also in state and i get it's value from async storage
fetch('http://192.1.1.:8000/api/students/' + this.state.id, {
    method: 'get',
  })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {  
        if (responseJson.message === 'success') {
          
            responseJson.data.map((userData) => {
            this.setState({student_name: userData.student_name})
            this.setState({class: userData.class})
            this.setState({section: userData.section})
        });
        }
```

that's how i get record from laravel and update state in react native. but when i use flat list in react native it throw me that error

```
VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or id property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor.
```

My react native view is like that

```
<View>
  <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>FlatList</Text>
    <FlatList 
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({item})=><Text style={{fontSize:50}}>{item.student_name}</Text>}
         />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a unique `key` (or `id`) prop for `Text` element in `FlatList`.

Supposing that your `this.state.data` items have an `id`, you could write something like:

```
<View>
  <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>FlatList</Text>
    <FlatList 
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({item})=><Text key={item.id} style={{fontSize:50}}>{item.student_name}</Text>}
         />
</View>
```

Alternatively, you could add `keyExtractor` to `FlatList` in this way:

```
<View>
      <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>FlatList</Text>
        <FlatList 
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({item})=><Text style={{fontSize:50}}>{item.student_name}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
             />
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Flatlist you have been need on key parameter . you must get that from list , like `id` parameter .
add this parameter to flatlist item

```
     style={styles.flatListStyle}
     data={this.state.bestSuggester}
     key={item => item.Rank}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are missing keyExtractor

Replace your code with this:

```
<View>
  <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>FlatList</Text>
    <FlatList 
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
      renderItem={({item})=><Text style={{fontSize:50}}>{item.student_name}</Text>}
   />
</View>
```